# Use MultiValueMap Request body

Tags: java, api, request, multivalue

I have a post mapping in my controller with @RequestBody MultiValueMap<String, String>.
Getting 415 unsupported media type error in post man while giving request body like this. Request type is json.

```
{
"name" : "john"
}
```

Can someone help on this?